# Laravel CustomServiceProvider Class not found in package when required

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I am having issues with a custom composer package I created to work for Laravel. I followed all the necessary steps others have said. First require the package, then `composer-dumpautoload -o`, and then add `ServiceProvider` to `config/app.php`. However, laravel cannot find the package ServiceProvider. Maybe my name spacing is off? Here is my code below along with the link to my github repo

https://github.com/InspiredByKeith/forecast-package

config/app.php

```
KeithRoye\Forecast\WeatherServiceProvider::class,
```

WeatherServiceProvider.php

```
 <?php

namespace KeithRoye\Forecast;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WeatherServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
    }
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Composer.json of package

```
{
    "name": "keithroye/forecast",
    "description": "This package will allow users to obtain a 5 day weather forecast based upon the given zip code provided.",
    "type": "library",
    "require-dev": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3@dev"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "KeithRoye\\Forecast": "src/"
        }
    },

    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Keith Roye",
            "email": "inspiredbykeith@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Composer.json of Application

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "keithroye/forecast": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `autoload-dev` => replace it with `autoload` (and do the same to `require-dev` => `require`).

The documentation of composer explains it, but I understand it's not clear if you're not familiar with the terminology.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev

> autoload-dev (root-only)
>   …

And the documentation for "root-only" i.e. [Root Package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package):

> Certain fields only apply when in the root package context.

I think example given there is quite good though:

> A package can be the root package or not, depending on the context. For example, if your project depends on the monolog library, your project is the root package. However, if you clone monolog from GitHub in order to fix a bug in it, then monolog is the root package.

#### Or to put it in another way

`autoload-dev` is only relevant when developing **your** package. Usually you define your tests there which are commonly put *next* to `src/` in `tests/` (on the same top-level) and thus they need a separate directive for that.

Comment: I will test this in a few hours when im on my lunch break, but I feel like this is it. Will let you know my results, unless you already tested and proven true.

Comment: @KeithRoye sure, fingers crossed 

Comment: Drinks on me :) haha. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `autoload-dev` with `autoload` and backslashes after `Forecast` in below section in composer.json.

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "KeithRoye\\Forecast\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

After edit this, run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dumpautoload` and check it again.

Answer (score -1):

You must include a leading backslash in the composer psr-4 definition namespace:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "KeithRoye\\Forecast\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. Still producing the same error.

Comment: Did you run `composer dump` after updating the JSON file? You can also manually confirm if the `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` was updated correctly with your namespace

Comment: Hey, Im not even seeing my composer package in that file. Can you do me a favor. My git repo was updated with your change. can you try to replicate what I am doing to see where I am going wrong. if you create a new laravel test app the url you should fire if using laravel valet is test.test/forecast?zip=32811 for example. you should an api token error unless you added one.